# How do I install the lastest Mesa driver in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, updates, intel-graphics, mesa

I'm suffering from this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/829086

Does anyone know how to fix this from reading the comments on the bug? There is a proposed workaround but I don't know how to compile things from source which you need to do to get the latest intel-gpu-tools. I thought it might be enough to install the latest Mesa package but how do I that without adding all the extra content from [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75) ppa? I want just the updated Mesa package but not the rest of the new content which the ppa will provide on a system update (which has broken many people's systems).

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can always download the packages individually and install them on your system.

Here is [the link](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa/+build/3000836) for the latest build for i386, and [the link](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa/+build/3000835) for the amd64 build.

The way to download files individually is to visit the PPA, click on *View package details*, select a package that you might be interested on downloading and the maintained builds will show allowing you to download the created package from that build.

Comment: One question though, which of all the files listed in the link should I download?

Comment: The mesa package for 11.10 Oneiric.

Comment: let me know if you have problems with that, ill guide you over step by step.

Comment: but there is libgles1-mesa, libgles2-mesa, libopenvg1-mesa, libosmesa, etc. Which one is the correct one? Should I download all that is not *-dev?

Comment: I will remove this post as the answer that answered my question since I haven't received enough information to actually install the latest Mesa driver. If I just get an answer to my latest comments here my question will be solved.